# Drives not appearing on desktop

Tags: macos, finder

I have gone into my Finder preferences and selected to show drives, connected servers, etc., on the desktop. They, however, do not appear. I have restarted Finder and rebooted, but they still are not there. Upon further examination, it also appears that when I click on the desktop, finder does not become the active application, clicking the desktop does nothing. It is as though the desktop has ceased to have functionality other then displaying an image.

Any idea how to correct this?

Comment: Are you sure you they are mounted? Can you see them in Finder?

Comment: Yes, they are right there in Finder

Comment: Can you drag documents onto the desktop and see them? If they're there, can you click on them, open them, etc.?

Comment: If I try to drag a document onto the desktop, when I release the mouse button the file disappears from view on the desktop and remains in its original folder. If I drag a document into the desktop shortcut on my sidebar, it does not appear on the desktop, but is visible when I select desktop in the sidebar

Comment: Do all users have the same issue? Have you tried to login as Guest or another user?

Comment: I just checked after your suggestion, it is just my user.

Comment: Then you can fix this by removing the Finder preferences for your user. Remove (backup...) com.apple.finder.plist and com.apple.sidebarlists.plist in ~/Library/Preferences/, reboot and you should be fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that CreateDesktop is set to false. Try running `defaults write com.apple.finder CreateDesktop -bool YES` in Terminal (unless you are on Mountain Lion or below, in which case the command is `defaults write com.apple.Finder CreateDesktop -bool YES`), followed by `killall Finder`. You should be able to view items on and drag items to your Desktop now, including drives.

Comment: I might be reading but wrong, but it seems that both of the Terminal lines are same. Are you sure you typed the second one right?

Comment: Capitalisation: finder/Finder

Answer (score 1):

If these kind of Finder problems are user specific, you can fix them by removing your Finder preference files in your Library.

The files you want to delete (backup) are:

- com.apple.sidebarlists.plist
- com.apple.finder.plist

You can find them in ~/Library/Preferences/ (Home -> Library -> Preferences).
Go to Finder, press <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> and paste `~/Library/Preferences/`

Now you need to relaunch Finder (logout/login, or reboot, or <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>esc</kbd>)

Answer (score 0):

This perhaps won't fix your bounty issue, but for Finder not correctly coming to the front... 
Opt-right click the Finder icon in the dock > Relaunch [bottom menu item] Should fix focussing issues with no side effects. For some reason, since Mountain Lion, this occasionally happens, Finder loses its focus, only some windows pop to the front when Finder is called - if you have multiple Spaces this seems more prevalent.

Comment: I relaunched Finder and that did not impact the focusing issue.

Comment: Then I'd be inclined to run Disk Utility, check perms & the disk; then run the combo updater for your current OS version. Google e.g. "osx combo update 10.9.4" for the correct file from Apple.

Comment: That did not work, unfortunately.